# How to post nested JSON in React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native

In react-native am using the fetch post method 
I want to send nested `JSON` in

```
method: 'POST',
headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
body: JSON.stringify({
```

// send below JSON to the backend

```
{
  "filterCriteria": {
    "catalogId": 0,
    "filterEnabled": "false"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a nested object and use it. It is not related to React Native. It is general JSON | Javascript concept.

```
let myData = 

{
  "filterCriteria": {
    "catalogId": 0,
    "filterEnabled": "false"
  }
};
```

THen use it where you want. Like;

...

```
method: 'POST',
headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
body: JSON.stringify(myData);
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `JSON` data then you can assign that `JSON` data to a variable,

```
const data = { "filterCriteria": { "catalogId": 0, "filterEnabled": "false" } }
```

And that data can be send to back-end like,

```
body: JSON.stringify(data)
```